# Discord.py json file prints all information instead of only the one being asked for

Tags: discord.py

I have code which enables the user to view a specific item in their list which is stored in a json file. But it prints everything from the json file. This is the code for the command:

```
@client.command(aliases = ["shib, shibaku, Shib"])
async def Shibaku(ctx, int = 0):

  if int == 1:
    with open('Shibaku1.json', 'r') as f:
      coins_data = json.load(f)
      for oslink in coins_data[str(ctx.author.id)]:
        await ctx.send(f'{oslink}')

  else:
    await ctx.send("Empty Slot")
```

7 items are stored in the json and they all get printed:

```
{
  "331971067788787733": [
    "\ud83d\ude04",
    "\ud83d\ude02",
    "\ud83d\ude00",
    "\ud83d\ude06",
    "\ud83d\ude18",
    "\ud83d\ude1d",
    "100",
    "https://opensea.io/assets/0xb70b759ad676b227a01f7d406e2dc9c67103aaeb/908"
  ]
}
```

I only need to print the link at the end

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send only laast element of the list use `coins_data[str(ctx.author.id)][-1]`:

```py
@client.command(aliases = ["shib, shibaku, Shib"])
async def Shibaku(ctx, int = 0):
  if int == 1:
    with open('Shibaku1.json', 'r') as f:
      coins_data = json.load(f)
      await ctx.send(coins_data[str(ctx.author.id)][-1])

  else:
    await ctx.send("Empty Slot")
```